# What version is org.springframework:spring-web relied by org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

When I opened pom.xml in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`, it says it relys on `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.3:compile`.
I created a spring boot project by intellij idea, everything is in default config, it relies `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE`, but when I run mvn dependency::tree, it says `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` relies on `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.3:compile`, which is against what is defined in starter-web's pom.xml.
Spring boot project's pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Result of `mvn dependency::tree` on this project is as follows:

```
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.41:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.16:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.30:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.602 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-06T10:31:24+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am wondering: why you need a different `spring-boot-starter-web` version? After all, `spring-boot-starter-parent` provides guaranteed compatible versions.

Comment: @DmitryRakovets That is making sense, when I deleted parent section, versions are as expected. Seems like ```spring-boot-starter-parent``` did something. BTW the reason I was adding the version tag is that I hope to get version info of its dependencies of that specific starter version.

Comment: You are mixing versions of Spring Boot, never mix versions of a framework, that will be trouble. Remove the `version` tag from the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency so that it uses the correct version. If you want to use 2.1 then change the version of the parent.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion!